# How do you loop over a mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm a java guy and I just don't understand why this won't work.

```
var results = QuestionEntryService.find( criteria );
while(results.hasNext()) {
  result = results.next();
  console.log(result);   
}
```

QuestionEntryService.find( criteria ) returns a mongoose model.Query object.    I can understand that results doesn't have a hasNext() because it's a mongo function rather than mongoose.   I tried using a callback but it never gets executed.

updated:
if I Console.log(results) it comes back with

```
model.Query {_mongooseOptions: Object, _transforms: Array(0), _hooks: Kareem, _executionCount: 0, mongooseCollection: NativeCollection, …}
```

Comment: how did u export your model ?

Answer (score 0):

when you use find() it gives you an array of results.and the way you try to get data using mongoose is wrong too
so when you want to iterate it try this

```
var results = QuestionEntryService.find( {criteria},(err, data)=>{ // this is a callback
for(let iteration of data){
  console.log(iteration);
}
});
```

when you develop using callbacks it will eventually take you to a callback hell problem. So try to use promises or async/await (best practice) .So,

```
async function findData(){
var results = await QuestionEntryService.find({})exec();
console.log(results); // print out the array of results


return results;
}
```

}

```
//consume promise
findData().then((results)=>{
for(let iteration of results){
console.log(iteration);
});
```

Schema

```
YourSchema = new Schema({
  you:{},
  me:{}
});

const model = module.exports = mongoose.model("model",YourSchema); // export your compiled mode
```

l

then access it from your rouuter

```
const model = require("./model"); // your file system

model.find({you:"name"},callback);
```

Comment: You should note that the resulting value would be a promise and can’t be used like normal functions

Comment: Hmm.. it never makes it to the callback.

Comment: what is your criteria?

Comment: It's a object with 2 String parameters.

Comment: is this a mongoose schema ?

Comment: Yes....   module.exports = {
  query: joi.object({
    me: joi.string().required(),
    you: joi.string().required()
  }).required()

Comment: ok then try like this const model = module.exports.blah blah blah ... and access that model using require("./model"); in your router and try again